# Running shell command using shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, centos, shell-exec

Im using an ajax call to execute "shell_exec" on the server (centos).
The line that im executing is the following

```
echo shell_exec("php -q /websockets/timedactions.php");
```

This is the server response:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.16
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myIpAddress
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-type: text/html

0
```

After running this command it seems that the process that it supposed to activate is not running.

Calling the same command on shell with root access

```
php -q /websockets/timedactions.php
```

works perfectly.

How can i make the script work using shell_exec ?

Comment: php binary may not be in the path, try it with full path name like  `shell_exec("/path/to/bin/php ...")`

Answer (score 0):

There can be errors, while the command is executed. You can redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, to see if there are any, [like this(Sample 3.5)](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).
`echo shell_exec("php -q /websockets/timedactions.php 2>&1");`

Also there could be something preventing `shell_exec` from printing ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#106250)).